# How to convert HTML content to PDF in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, jspdf, html2canvas

I am trying to generate the PDF file from HTML content.
contentDataURL is having the empty image data. I have tried changing the HTML content also but the same empty image is getting generated.
What's wrong with my `canvas.toDataURL()` implementation?
PDF file generation is working fine.

my code app link
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-1aug8i

```html
<div class="test" id="test">
     <button (click)="sendToPdf()"> 
         testpdf</button> </div>
         <div class="abc" id="testdivid">
            <table style="width:100%">
                <tr>
                  <th>Firstname</th>
                  <th>Lastname</th>
                  <th>Age</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Jill</td>
                  <td>Smith</td>
                  <td>50</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Eve</td>
                  <td>Jackson</td>
                  <td>94</td>
                </tr>
              </table>
         </div>
```

```
import html2canvas from 'html2canvas';
import jspdf from 'jspdf';


sendToPdf(){
  let data = document.getElementById("test"); 
    // let data = document.getElementById("maindiv");
    console.log(data);  
    html2canvas(data).then(canvas => {
      const contentDataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 1.0)
      console.log(contentDataURL);  
      let pdf = new jspdf('l', 'cm', 'a4'); //Generates PDF in landscape mode
      // let pdf = new jspdf('p', 'cm', 'a4'); //Generates PDF in portrait mode
      pdf.addImage(contentDataURL, 'PNG', 0, 0, 29.7, 21.0);  
      pdf.save('Filename.pdf');   
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Please check this:https://therichpost.com/how-to-convert-html-into-pdf-in-angular-10/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after reinstalling html2canvas worked fine

```
import html2canvas from 'html2canvas';
import jspdf from 'jspdf';


sendToPdf(){
  let data = document.getElementById("test"); 
    // let data = document.getElementById("maindiv");
    console.log(data);  
    html2canvas(data).then(canvas => {
      const contentDataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 1.0)
      console.log(contentDataURL);  
      let pdf = new jspdf('l', 'cm', 'a4'); //Generates PDF in landscape mode
      // let pdf = new jspdf('p', 'cm', 'a4'); //Generates PDF in portrait mode
      pdf.addImage(contentDataURL, 'PNG', 0, 0, 29.7, 21.0);  
      pdf.save('Filename.pdf');   
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To use your code in Angular13+ you must add 2 lines of code, otherwise there will be an Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'HTMLElement' Error:

You may use:

```
  sendToPdf() {
    let data = document.getElementById('test');
    // let data = document.getElementById("maindiv");
    console.log(data);
    if (data != null) {
      html2canvas(data).then((canvas) => {
        const contentDataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 1.0);
        console.log(contentDataURL);
        let pdf = new jsPDF('l', 'cm', 'a4'); //Generates PDF in landscape mode
        // let pdf = new jspdf('p', 'cm', 'a4'); //Generates PDF in portrait mode
        pdf.addImage(contentDataURL, 'PNG', 0, 0, 29.7, 21.0);
        pdf.save('Filename.pdf');
      });
    }
  }
```